# Comparing contract instance to an address in solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity

So I've updated solidity to version 0.5.0 and I'm trying to re-write my code. One thing that worked before was comparing contract (represented by its address) to addresses. So now I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types contract User and address payable
```

Then I've tried to just add the address field, but the compiler won't allow it. For instance, the following won't compile because it expects **;** instead of **.** :

```
address a = User.address;
```

So how do I solve this problem of getting the address field from a contract so the compiler lets me compare those two? Here is the part of the code that won't compile because of that **require** statement:

```
mapping(address=>User) public users;

function register(string memory _nome) public {
    require(users[msg.sender]==0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
    users[msg.sender] = new User(_nome,msg.sender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "that if statement" you mean the `require`?

Just use an explicit cast to `address`:

```
require(address(users[msg.sender]) == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
```

Comment: yes, I'll correct it

Comment: that works, thanks. I've assumed casting was not yet implemented in solidity so I didn't bother trying.